# How can I find out if a relative symlink is internal to a certain subtree or not?

Tags: bash, shell, symlink

I want to test if a relative symlink points within the subtree of a certain directory.

This example would yield `false` since it points outside the `foo` directory:
`/foo>readlink bar

../fie.txt`

While this example would yield `true`:
`/foo>readlink bar

fum/fie.txt`

Is there an existing utility I can leverage or will I have to code it from scratch? I'm using `bash`.

Comment: What if `fie.txt` or `fum` is itself a symlink outside `foo`?

Comment: Would you always run this from `/foo` or do you need to be able to pass arbitrary directories? I mean, is the question always with respect to `./` or not?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Yeah, that's a problem that I choose to ignore, sort of at least. I'm thinking I'll expand the link using readlink -f and see if the prefixes match. But I will ignore crazy corner cases since they don't exist in our environment.

Comment: @terdon No, it should accept arbitrary directories.

Comment: Have a look at [symlinks](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/symlinks8.html), it _may_ help.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's such an utility. With GNU `readlink`, you could do something like:

```
is_in() (
  needle=$(readlink -ve -- "$1" && echo .) || exit
  haystack=$(readlink -ve -- "$2" && echo .) || exit
  needle=${needle%??} haystack=${haystack%??}
  haystack=${haystack%/} needle=${needle%/}
  case $needle in
    ("$haystack" | "$haystack"/*) true;;
    (*) false;;
  esac
)
```

That resolves *all* symlinks to end up with a canonical absolute path for both needle and haystack.

#### Explanation

- We get the canonical absolute path of both the *needle* and the *haystack*. We use `-e` instead of `-f` as we want to make sure the files exist. The `-v` option gives an error message if the files can't be accessed.
- As always, `--` should be used to mark the end of options and quoting as we don't want to invoke the split+glob operator here.
- Command substitution in Bourne-like shells have a misfeature in that it removes *all* the newline character from the end the output of a command, not just the one added by commands to end the last line. What that means is that for a file like `/foo<LF><LF>`, `$(readlink -ve -- "$1")` would return `/foo`. The common work-around for that is to append a non-LF character (here `.`) and strip that and the extra LF character added by `readlink` with `var=${var%??}` (remove the last two characters).
- The needle is regarded as being in the haystack if it is the haystack or if it is haystack/something. However, that wouldn't work if the haystack was `/` (`/etc` for instance is not `//something`). `/` often needs to be treated specially because while `/` and `/xx` have the same number of slashes, one is a level above the other.

  One way to address it is to replace `/` with the empty string which is done with `var=${var%/}` (the only path ending with `/` that `readlink -e` may output is `/`, so removing a trailing `/` is changing `/` to the empty string).

For the canonizing of the file paths, you could use a helper function.

```
canonicalize_path() {
  # canonicalize paths stored in supplied variables. `/` is returned as 
  # the empty string.
  for _var do
    eval '
      '"$_var"'=$(readlink -ve -- "${'"$_var"'}" && echo .) &&
      '"$_var"'=${'"$_var"'%??} &&
      '"$_var"'=${'"$_var"'%/}' || return
  done
}

is_in() (
  needle=$1 haystack=$2
  canonicalize_path needle haystack || exit
  case $needle in
    ("$haystack" | "$haystack"/*) true;;
    (*) false;;
  esac
)
```

Comment: I found studying this post very instructive.  May I ask you a couple of questions?  Is there any significance in the fact that in `needle=${needle%??} haystack=${haystack%??}` the `needle` variable is dealt with first, whereas in the next line it is the other way around?  Also, how come your `return` statements don't explicitly return a non-zero value (to indicate error)?  Last one: would it make sense to factor out the entire transformation (the call to `readlink`, plus the two suffix truncations) to a separate `_canonicalize_path` helper function?

Comment: @kjo, 1) no significance 2) `return` returns by default with the status of the last command. With `|| return`,  that allows to return the status as provided by the failing application. 3) sure, but the resulting function will likely not be a pleasant sight. I'll add an example.

Comment: Thanks!  I see what you mean!  Not a pleasant sight at all.  Shell programming must be the hardest type of programming I know of...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:

`echo $abs_link_target | grep -qe "^$containing_dir"`

The `$abs_link_target` variable contains the absolut path to the symlink target (expanded through `readlink -f`). I then check to see if the beginning of the target path matches the beginning of the `$containing_dir`

Comment: It would says that /foobar is in /foo

Comment: It would say that /abc/d is in /a.b (`$containing_dir` taken as a regexp)

Comment: It would say that /abc is in `/foo<LF>/abc` (the lines of the pattern string are treated as different patterns to match)

Comment: It would say that `/foo<LF>/abc` is in `/abc` (`grep` matches on each line of the input, not the whole input so generally can't be used to match file names).

Comment: Depending on the `echo` implementation and/or the environment, you'll have issues with filenames containing backslashes [`echo` should really not be used to handle arbitrary data](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/22565)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Okay, scenario 3 and 4 is really stretching it, having <LF> in a directory/filename is just silly. Scenario 1 is very valid, but should be solvable if you make sure that the `$containing_dir` ends with a `/`. Scenario 2 I don't really understand, do you actually mean /a.c, and that the . is a wildcard?

Comment: yes sorry, should have been `/a.c`, see my answer for a more correct solution

Comment: Almost forgot: you'll have problems with filenames containing blank or wildcard characters as well since you're not quoting `$abs_link_target`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Ah okay, I think I'll still go with the current solution as it is much easier to realize what's going on in it. Mostly because the people who will maintain it aren't super well versed in bash. And also because the domain where this script is used won't have wildcards in the filenames. Your answer is probably much more robust though.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -q "^/foo/bar/" <<< "$(readlink -f "anyfile.ext")"`

Comment: Assuming the target of `anyfile.ext` exists and is reachable (otherwise, `readlink -f` as opposed to `readlink -e` might not give you the correct path) and that the resulting path doesn't contain newline characters (assumes zsh or bash4 or ksh93m+ or above). Note that if `anyfile.ext` points to `/foo/bar` itself, it will say it's not within.